# Android, horizontal progressBar filled from center to sides

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I need to draw a horizontal progressBar, but instead of fill from left to right or from Right to left, I need that ir can be filled from center to sides.

I've read all I've found and find out any library that allow me to do this, But I haven't found anything.
I can do it drawing rectagles, but I'll need to do some calculations to keep dimensions and so on...

Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could quite easily do this by yourself, by combining 2 progressbars.

1 to the left, that goes right-to-left, and 1 to the right, that goes left-to-right.
Then just set the same progress on both of them, without any space in between them. This would create the illusion of 1 progress bar that grows from the middle and outward.

If you really do want a library, this library could do it for you:
https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much. I've tought about to use a couple of bars, anywaya I'll check the library out, it looks promising.

Comment: Glad i could be of assistance, if you found my answer satisfying, please accept the answer and upvote it.